# Jquery: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what causes this problem (thought I covered it correctly). What happens is that on click, it should apply the grow class (which is 0.8 seconds) and after that flip over. Else it reverses this proces.

```
$('.click').toggle(function(){
    var self = this;
    $(this).removeClass('normal');
    $(this).addClass('grow');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(self).addClass('flip')
    }800);  <-- getting my error here
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flip');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).addClass('normal');
        $(this).removeClass('grow');
    }800);
});
```

Yet I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` on the first setTimeout (and probably ont he second one) but I dont see why i missed a `)`

Comment: You've missed the comma following the closing `}` after the first argument to `setTimeout`

Comment: you are missing a , before the 800

Comment: missing a comma before the 800

Comment: you are missing a comma before the 800

Comment: @haxtbh +1 for the 9 secs faster answer :-)

Comment: Has anyone mentioned that you are missing a comma?

Comment: Go back to work guyz ^^

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies ... I feel stupid :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `,` before the timeout amount.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(self).addClass('flip')
    }800);
```

should be

```
   setTimeout(function(){
        $(self).addClass('flip')
    },800);
```

Comment: Jep spotted it, thansk :) Will accept as awnser ... just the long timeout .. untill i can accept it ... you see your points in 10 minutes

Comment: Typo questions should be close-voted, not answered, usually with a comment (like your original).